# MongoDB find query with nested documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following document structure in my MongoDB:

```
[{
  "_id": "59afce079af65f48de8fb609",
  "some_fields": "...",
  "members": [
    {
      "some_fields": "...",
      "device_id": "7FD45D19-F746-4293-A410-60B485E617F2",
      "_id": "59afce079af65f48de8fb60a"
    },
    {
      "some_fields": "...",
      "device_id": "7AC1635B-3E39-4F43-A4D4-4927FA072F89",
      "_id": "59afd01cff27894e8237eb2d"
    }
  ]
}]
```

How can I get `documents which members contain object where device_id == "given_id"` using Mongoose's find ?

Comment: What did you try? Have you even read [Query Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/)?

Answer (score 0):

Try for this:

Use elemMatch:

```
db.collection.find({members: {$elemMatch: {device_id:'your ID'}}})
```

Comment: You don't "need" `$elemMatch`. Simple ["dot notation"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) will do. It's this sort of misinformation that is really damaging.

Comment: @NeilLunn With the elemMatch he can also compare more that 1 element..

Comment: You only **"need"** [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) for **more than one condition**. This is only a **single condition**. People thinking otherwise is a real problem. The documentation is actually very clear when you read it. You have both links there, so I suggest you read them yourself.

Comment: BTW. Don't presume that since I commented that I was the person who downvoted. Not my style. I just corrected what was incorrectly stated. You only get downvotes from me for a "completely incorrect" answer.

Comment: @NeilLunn No no.. I won't take that serious if anybody downvoted my post. Different people will have different perspective.